# Data randomly disapeared

Tags: login, files, data-loss, user-data

**Background:** Last night i stayed up until 4am installing the jdk as well as discord and skype. This morning i was playing some games and everything was fine until i packed up my computer to go home. When i arrived home and booted up my computer (after charging it since it was dead). **Current problem:** I typed in my password while admiring my clock background then the background changed and all my bar icons were set to the defaults and desktop had no icons.  All of my apps are there but my personal data is gone. My jdk files are there too so idk what caused it. This was the 2nd boot since installing everything btw

Comment: Did you log onto the Guest Session by accident perhaps?

Comment: I went to log of and back in and its checked marked... i feel like a noob . You can answer it

Comment: It happened to me for the first time in my life (well 3 year Ubuntu life) for the first time last week which was the only reason I answered so quickly. I will post a full answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We you log onto Ubuntu and the resolution mysteriously changes or all your desktop icons are gone, chances are good you logged into a "Guest Session" the simple solution is to log off and log back on using your "normal" account.

In some cases you may need to reboot if your software behaves abnormally like conky did in this AU Question: ([Accidentally logged into Guest account, then normal account & conky broken](https://askubuntu.com/questions/878502/accidentally-logged-into-guest-account-then-normal-account-conky-broken)) where I logged out of "Guest Session" and immediately logged into "normal" account without rebooting.